# Current user in django admin

Tags: python, django, admin, httprequest

I've tried numerous methods of finding the current user ID in django's administration. I've tried pulling the user ID via SessionKey and request.user (HTTPRequest) to no avail. My latest incarnation is:

```
def save(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if getattr(obj, 'submitter', None) is None:
        obj.submitter = request.user
    obj.save()

    super(AppAdmin, self).save()
```

in admin.py and

```
submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="submitter")
```

in models.py. I found this elsewhere on stack overflow, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the looks of your snippet, you are trying to save the currently logged in user to your model field in a `ModelAdmin`

It looks like you meant to override `save_model`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

```
class AppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.submitter = request.user # no need to check for it.
        obj.save()
```